# Payment with large amount causes “CREDIT_CARD_REFUSED" error in Paypal REST API

Tags: paypal, credit-card, paypal-rest-sdk

I have integrated the Payment Rest API in my web app to receive payment from customers. Sometimes when the customer initiates payment above $2500 from my app, the payment got failed with an error, "**CREDIT_CARD_REFUSED**".
But their card is valid and they can successfully pay their money using the same card through the Paypal Guest checkout.

We are facing this kind of issue frequently. I didn't find any information regarding this in any of the Paypal documents and community forums.

Are there any payment limit for credit cards when paying it through the Payment REST API? Please help us with your valuable information.

The error message we got from Paypal REST API is,**{"name":"CREDIT_CARD_REFUSED","message":"Credit card was refused.","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#errors","debug_id":"cee2e74de74b3"}**

Comment: Hi Benasir, sounds like it didn't pass the PayPal authorization system. Essentially, the card info is incorrect or they've hit the limit as a guest for PayPal guest checkout [credit card guest option, not signing in ]. You double check the card number or cvv?

Comment: @GeekNinja customer said that card number and cvv is correct only. Can you please share me what is the hit limit as a guest?

Comment: Yeh sure. It's usually 15 times.